# Deleting a file inside a directory with excluding a folder inside

Tags: linux, unix

I have a folder structure like below. I am deleting all files inside /data/mydata/ which are older than 2 hrs using the command below, but I want to exclude the metadata folder. How can I do it?

Command:

```
/usr/bin/find /data/mydata -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete -o -cmin +120 -type f -delete
```

Directory structure:

```
/data/mydata/
          --test1
               --f2.txt
               --foo
               --metadata
                  --test1.json
          --test2
               --metadata
                   --foo(under metadata)
                      --test2.json
                --f2.txt
```

Comment: Use `-prune` ...

Comment: eg `find /data/mydata -path /data/mydata/test2/metadata -prune  -o -mindepth 1...`

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a particular path, you can do:

```
/usr/bin/find /data/mydata -path /data/mydata/test2/metadata -prune \
        -o -mindepth 1 \( \( -type d -empty \) -o \( -cmin +120 -type f \) \) -delete
```

To exclude all instances of directories named metadata, you probably want:

```
/usr/bin/find /data/mydata -name metadata -prune \
            -o -mindepth 1 \( \( -type d -empty \) -o \
                           \( -cmin +120 -type f \) \) -delete
```

Comment: Thanks.What will happen to test1/metadata I want to exclude it as well.

Comment: It will not be excluded. But you can simply add `-path /data/mydata/test1/metadata -prune`

Comment: Well for automating I am looking generic way to exclude. It can be test3/metadata ,test4/metadata

Comment: `-name metadata -prune` should give you what you want.

Comment: I get this /usr/bin/find: The -delete action automatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.

Comment: @constantlearner — consider using `-exec rm {} +` instead of `-delete` because that does not turn on `-depth`.

Comment: Posix standard says this about `-prune`: "The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory. If the -depth primary is specified, the -prune primary shall have no effect."

Comment: POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) says: `-prune`
_The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory. If the `-depth` primary is specified, the `-prune` primary shall have no effect._ .

Comment: It does not delete anything I get the warning."/usr/bin/find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."

Comment: This is the final command    /usr/bin/find /data/mydata  -name metadata -prune \
            -o -mindepth 1 \( \( -type d -empty \) -o \
                           \( -cmin +120 -type f \) \) -exec rm {} +

Comment: /usr/bin/find /data2/scalable_uploads -name metadata -prune  -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm {} +  -o -cmin +0 -type f -exec rm {} +  works but does not delete  directory test1 and test2

Comment: test1 and test2 are not empty, so they won't be deleted.  If you want to consider "emtpy" to mean "has no entries other than metadata", you'll need to write some more logic.